# Maximum Length of Title and Meta Description

Tags: php, get

There is a request that works well.

The query takes the description text and carries it to the meta description in html code. The problem is that the description text is very long, and the meta description should be limited to 200 characters. How to do it?

Query text:

```
if( sobi2Config::request( $_REQUEST, 'sobi2Task', null ) == 'sobi2Details' ) {
    $metaDesc .= '';
} else {
    $metaDesc .= $config->getSobiStr( $config->getSobiStr( $comMeta->description ) );
}
```

Comment: How to do __what__?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function. You can use it like this :

```
if( sobi2Config::request( $_REQUEST, 'sobi2Task', null ) == 'sobi2Details' ) {
    $metaDesc .= '';
} else {
    $metaDesc .= substr( $config->getSobiStr( $config->getSobiStr( $comMeta->description ) ), 0, 200);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much and good luck! Your code works perfectly!